# dreamweaver template master.css is not on the local disk

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, dreamweaver-templates

I'm designing on dreamweaver. I have an html file and a css from which I have made a template. However, it seems that the css file has not been included in the template since ".dwt" file does not show any of the styles mentioned in the css and it shows a message as follows:

> master.css is not on the local disk

and it has a "get" link beside it which is not active. I will be very grateful if you kindly help me solve this problem.

Comment: What is the version of dreamweaver and which template you are using, like (HTML template = 3 column fixed, header and footer)???

Comment: @Mary I am using dreamweaver version CS6 the css file is mentioned in "index.html" through <link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> and I am using "select File -> Save as template" to make a template out of index.html

Answer (score 1):

You must verify that the master.css this located in the same folder as the template you created.

Comment: @ Juan I have "main folder" in which I have css folder in which there is .css file and the index.html from which I made the template is in the "main folder".

Answer (score 1):

This quite simple. Go to Site/Site Options/Check links sitewide. Click on the broken links, browse and locate them and your done.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to sources through the 'CSS Designer' on the left-side panel:

[Left-panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF6vu.png)

then, add the source as to 'attach the existing CSS file' or 'create a new CSS file'. This way it is on the local disk or same folder as the html document.